# $ p(x) $ as a product of irreducible (over $ \mathbb{F}$) factors.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Hello can you help me with this problem?

Let $ p(x) = x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + 2x + 2 \in \mathbb{Z}_5 [x].$ Construct the field $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{Z}_5 [x] \setminus \langle x^3 + 2x + 1 \rangle      $ and write $ p(x) $ as a product of irreducible (over $  \mathbb{F}$) factors.

We know that $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{Z}_5 [x] \setminus \langle x^3 + 2x + 1 \rangle      $ So if we suppose that the root of $x^3 + 2x + 1 $ is $\alpha$ we will get:
$$  \alpha^3 + 2 \cdotp \alpha + 1 = 0  $$
$$  \Downarrow $$
$$  \alpha^3 = -\left( 2 \cdotp \alpha + 1 \right) $$
Now let's find $  \alpha^4  $ and $\alpha^5$

$\alpha^3 = -\left(  2 \cdotp \alpha +1\right) $

$\alpha^4 = \alpha^3 \cdotp \alpha = -\left(  2 \cdotp \alpha +1\right) \cdotp \alpha = -\left(  2 \cdotp \alpha^2 +\alpha\right) $

$\alpha^5 = \alpha^4 \cdotp \alpha = -\left(  2 \cdotp \alpha^2 +\alpha\right) \cdotp \alpha = -\left(  2 \cdotp \alpha^3 +\alpha^2\right) = 4 \cdotp \alpha - \alpha^2 + 2$

$$ \Downarrow $$
$$  p(\alpha) = 4 \alpha - \alpha^2 + 2 -2\alpha^2 - \alpha - 2 \alpha - 1 = -3\alpha^2 + \alpha + 1 $$

Is this solution right?

Comment: You need to find the factors of $p(x) $ with coefficients in field extension $\mathbb {F} $.

Comment: I'm fairly sure I commented on this exact problems relatively recently, but cannot find it now. Was it yours? Did you delete it? Anyway, the question is not about finding $p(\alpha)$. It is about factoring $p(x)$ over the field $\Bbb{Z}_5(\alpha)$.

Comment: I would say that to solve this problem it is imperative that you first factor $p(x)$ over the prime field $\Bbb{Z}_5$. It turns out to be irreducible. At that point you are done because a general result depending on $\gcd(3,5)=1$ kicks in.

Comment: In other words, the question is somewhat analogous to the following: Let $K$ be the field $K=\Bbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-2)=\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$, where $\alpha=\sqrt2$. Factor the polynomials $f(x)=x^2-2x-1$ and $g(x)=x^2-3$ over $K$. It turns out that $g(x)$ stays irreducible over $K$ because $\sqrt3\notin K$. But $f(x)$ factors over $K$ as
$$f(x)=(x-1-\alpha)(x-1+\alpha).$$ All because its zeros are $1\pm\sqrt2$.

Comment: Anyway. Nobody is interested in $\alpha^4$ or $\alpha^5$. Yet another example. The polynomial $x^2+2$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{R}$, but it factors over $\Bbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)$ as $x^2+2=(x+i\sqrt2)(x-i\sqrt2)$ where $i$ is the element $x+(x^2+1)$ in the field $\Bbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)$ better known by another name.

Comment: Now, if you need to factor $x^3-2$ over $\Bbb{R}(i)$ (see the previous comment), it won't help you to calculate what $i^3-2$ is, will it?

Comment: Anyway, I think that you have a gap in your understanding of what is being asked here. You seem to be missing several pieces of the required theory to do much here. For example, what do you know about field extensions, towers of such, and degrees of towers?